# What is keyboard shortcut to close terminal window?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I'm wondering if there is keyboard shortcut to close terminal window?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An active terminal will quit if you tell it there's [no more input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110248/880).
That can be done with a quick <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>.

If you have things running (or something already typed into a terminal input), that won't work. You'll either have exit or clear the line. <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will *usually* work for that.

Alternatively, running `exit` isn't much of a hardship.

Note that these will bump you out of one layer of shell. If you start this in a subshell of a subshell, logged into something over SSH, it'll take a few goes to close the window.

Comment: Thanks again... I knew of [Ctrl][D] for applications, just never tried it on `bash` itself...

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>

If you go to menu  **FILE > CLOSE WINDOW**
you will see the shortcut there, and many others

Alternatively,
(this is a general approach running I would say any application under GNOME)

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>